# Prevent from inserting columns without triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a two field in table, Column1 and Column2

```
Column1 | Column2
-------------------
 F      |   B
 A      |   C
--------------
 B           F    needs prevention
 C           A    needs prevention
```

how can I prevent    (B,F)   and (C,A) from inserting without the triggers?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to prevent an insert that will be the exact opposite from a row you already have.

One way to do it is by adding a check constraint and a unique index:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Column1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Column2 char(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT chk_Col1AndCol2 CHECK(Column1 <= Column2)
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_MyTable 
    ON dbo.MyTable (Column1, Column2);
GO
```

This check constraint prevents Column1 to hold values that are bigger than the values in Column2.

If you don't want to limit column1 to be smaller or equal to column2,
another option is to use a check constraint with a user defined funtion:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Column1 char(1) NOT NULL,
    Column2 char(1) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_MyTable  -- Again, same unique index
    ON dbo.MyTable (Column1, Column2);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_CheckMyTable
(
    @Column1 char(1),
    @Column2 char(1)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Column1 = @Column2
        AND Column2 = @Column1
    )

END;
GO

ALTER TABLE MyTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_MyTable1 CHECK(dbo.fn_CheckMyTable(Column1, Column2) = 0);
GO
```

Comment: isn't it possible to do it just with Table Constraint?

Comment: A check constraint can not contain queries. For that you must use a user defined function. You can use only the check constraint and unique index like in the first code example I've written.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to prevent this using 
[check constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    COLUMN1 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    COLUMN2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MY_CONSTRAINT CHECK ((COLUMN1, COLUMN2) NOT IN (('B','F'), ('C','A')))
);
```

Of course the syntax may differ from provider to provider.

Comment: I dont want to mention the exact Data inside the constraint. It should be dynamic, cause it could be anything

Comment: Error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.` !!

Comment: You didn't specify anything about dynamic data in your question. In such case you should consider another table of "allowed values" to which your main table will point via foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trigger-nestlevel-transact-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE t(col1 CHAR(5), col2 CHAR(5));
CREATE TABLE t_helper(i CHAR(5));

CREATE TRIGGER trg_t_helper ON t_helper
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t(col1, col2)
   SELECT i, 'B'
   FROM inserted;
END;


CREATE TRIGGER trg_t ON t
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL( OBJECT_ID('trg_t_helper'),'AFTER', 'DML'))= 0)  
  RAISERROR('Direct data insert are disabled.',16,-1);
END;
```

Check:

```
INSERT INTO t_helper(i) VALUES ('Z');

SELECT * FROM t;
--col1  col2
--Z     B  

INSERT INTO t(col1, col2) VALUES ('A', 'B');
```

> Msg 50000 Level 16 State 1 Line 6
>
> Direct data insert are disabled.

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=22d961b73275e9dd171a2169cf149124)**

Comment: isn't it possible without the trigger?